# How do I get a valid xmodmap while using xcape

Tags: linux, xorg, xmodmap

I'll admit at the start that X's key-mapping is a bit of a black-art for me which mainly involves copy and pasting examples from places like SO and SU and seeing if it works. However in this case I need to better understand what's happened to get xcape and i3lock to play nicely together.

I'm using the xcape utility to handle mapping my return key to an alternative Control when long pressed and still behave as a normal key press when pressed and released. The setup for this looks like:

```
if [ -e ${XCAPE} ]; then
    killall xcape 2> /dev/null
    ${XMODMAP} -e 'keycode 36 = 0x1234'
    ${XMODMAP} -e 'add control = 0x1234'
    ${XMODMAP} -e 'keycode any = Return'
    ${XCAPE} -e '0x1234=Return'
    KEYMAPS="${KEYMAPS} StRet->Ctrl"
fi
```

As I understand this it remaps the return key (36) to a fake key (0x1234). It then modifies the map so control is also mapped onto (0x1234). xcape then does "magic" to ensure the right keycode is sent depending on the long press.

This all works fine however it breaks my screen lock program (i3lock) which does some manipulation of the X keyboard map before it starts. It fails with the following message:

```
Error:    (unknown file):1092:13: syntax error
Error:    Failed to parse input xkb file
[i3lock] xkb_keymap_new_from_file failed
i3lock: Could not load keymap
```

Adding some debugging to dump out the keymap I surmised it was the following line that caused confusion.

```
xkb_symbols "pc_gb_inet(evdev)_ctrl(nocaps)" {

    name[group1]="English (UK)";
    key     <> {         [          Return ] };
    key  <ESC> {         [          Escape ] };
    key <AE01> {
    ...
```

So what has happened to trip things up? Are the two fundamentally incompatible? Will I need to partially restore the keymap before I run i3lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much digging it turns out the first 'keycode any = Return' sets keycode 8 which confuses the i3lock key map processing. In addition you need to ensure keycode 36 does generate a return so you can enter your password.

I wrapped the call to i3lock in a script, so in my i3 config:

```
# background, screensaver and locking
exec xautolock -time 10 -locker '/home/alex/.config/i3/lock_screen.sh'
bindsym $mod+l exec /home/alex/.config/i3/lock_screen.sh
```

With the lock screen script being a simple:

```
# The initial key-sequence chosen by xcape does confuse i3lock so we reset it
xmodmap -e "keycode 8 = "
# Ensure the return key does work as intended
xmodmap -e 'keycode 36 = Return'
i3lock -c 334433
```